# Can't get an old WIN32 WINAPI program to compile

Tags: c++, winapi, win64

I tried CodeBlocks and MS VC++ 2010 but both fail to compile.

They can't find the definition for PlaySound() in .
What is the Problem?

```
case WM_CREATE:
    PlaySound (TEXT("hellowin.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC) ;
    return 0 ;
```

Errors:

```
error C2065: 'SND_FILENAME': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
error C2065: 'SND_ASYNC': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
error C3861: "PlaySound": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.
```

windows.h is included in stdafx.h
but even if I include it directly in codeblocks it doesn't work.

Comment: Put `#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before the #include and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols for `PlaySound` and `SND_…` are declared in `mmsystem.h` header and defined in the `winmm.lib` library. You must include and link against those.

Comment: mmsystem.h should be included in windows.h (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)#requirements)

Comment: Shouldn't they be included in windows.h? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: If `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined, `windows.h` does not include `mmsystem.h` (and many others)

Answer (score 1):

`PlaySound` function is declared in `Mmsystem.h` (which is included by `Windows.h`). Make sure to include that. See more on that function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85)).
Note that if `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined, `Windows.h` does not include `Mmsystem.h`. Make sure to `#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before `#include <Windows.h>` if you notice a problem.

Then if you have a linker error, read a little more from the book this exercise comes from (Programming Windows 5th ed Chapter 2):

> A couple of warnings: If you use Microsoft Visual C++ to create a new
>   project for this program, you need to make an addition to the object
>   libraries the linker uses. Select the Settings option from the Project
>   menu, and pick the Link tab. Select General from the Category list
>   box, and add WINMM.LIB (“Windows multimedia”) to the Object/Library
>   Modules text box. You need to do this because HELLOWIN makes use of a
>   multimedia function call, and the multimedia object library isn’t
>   included in a default project. Otherwise you’ll get an error message
>   from the linker indicating that the PlaySound function is unresolved.

Comment: The question is asking about compiler errors. This answer tries to solve linker errors. Not applicable, sorry. Not sure why this received 3 upvotes.

Comment: The edit doesn't help. The OP doesn't get a compiler error for the symbol [WM_CREATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create) (which is introduced by including ´Windows.h`). This answer does not address the issue.

Comment: The link you provided mentions that `WM_CREATE` can be introduced by `Winuser.h` without `Windows.h`.

Comment: A comment would be the right tool to verify this. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865928/cant-get-an-old-win32-winapi-program-to-compile#comment107688014_60865928) is likely much closer to the issue (which should be an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try including `MMSystem.h`  and `Windows.h` because by default, `MMSystem.h` should be included in `Windows.h,` but when `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined, `Windows.h` will not include it.
And you should also add `winmm.lib` to the linker (by typing `-lwinmm`) because symbols of `PlaySound`, `SND_SYNC`, `SND_ASYNC` and `SND_FILENAME` are defined there.

Comment: Include "windows.h" and "mmsystem.h" and type "-lwinmm" or "winmm.lib" in the linker's additional parameters.